# npm install failing using babel-presets / chai / mocha

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, babeljs, chai

On Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with Node v0.10.40 and NPM 1.4.28

`npm install` is failing, I don't even get all my soft links in `node_modules/.bin` I expect.

It seems to be something to do with `chai`, `webpack`, `webpack-dev-server` and `babel-preset-es2015` / `babel-preset-react`. If I take out Chai for example it works. If I take out the babel-preset packages it works. If they are all there, it doesn't.

**Minimal broken packages.json**

Here is a small `packages.json` config that breaks:

```
{
  "name": "voting-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js 'test/**/*.@(js|jsx)'",
    "test:watch": "npm run test --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.20",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
    "chai": "^3.4.0",
    "mocha": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

**Actual packages.json**

Here's my actual `packages.json` config that also breaks:

```
{
  "name": "voting-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js 'test/**/*.@(js|jsx)'",
    "test:watch": "npm run test --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.20",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
    "chai": "^3.4.0",
    "chai-immutable": "^1.5.1",
    "jsdom": "^7.0.2",
    "mocha": "^2.3.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "immutable": "^3.7.5",
    "react": "^0.14.2",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.2"
  }
}
```

**Error from npm install**

Looking more closely at the `npm install` I can see it is failing on a sub-package `utf-8-validate`. I know my gypsy install works because it compiles `socket.io` no problem in another project.

```
web23@wendy:/var/www/io.ofbeaton.com/web/dev/voting-client$ npm install
npm WARN package.json voting-client@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json voting-client@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json voting-client@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.5
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.5
\
> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /var/www/clients/client1/web23/web/dev/voting-client/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/var/www/clients/client1/web23/web/dev/voting-client/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
Killed
web23@wendy:/var/www/io.ofbeaton.com/web/dev/voting-client$   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory `/var/www/clients/client1/web23/web/dev/voting-client/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
```

See the `Killed` line in particular. That is all the output I get on broken installs. How is this happening? How can I fix it?

**Working example without presets:**

Here's a working `package.json` without the babel-presets.

```
{
  "name": "voting-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js 'test/**/*.@(js|jsx)'",
    "test:watch": "npm run test --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.20",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.1",   
    "chai": "^3.4.0",
    "mocha": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

**Edit: Is the problem an old node version?**

https://github.com/websockets/utf-8-validate/issues/18 seemed to indicate an old node version would cause this.

So I upgraded node to v5.0.0 and npm to 3.3.6.

Here's the 'npm install' output:

```
web23@wendy:/var/www/io.ofbeaton.com/web/dev/voting-client$ npm install
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
extract → gunzTarPerm     ▐ ╢█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
Killed
```

No dice.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem was indeed the `utf-8-validate` issue when compiling on older versions of node. For that I followed [digitalocean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) to use use the v5.0.0 version. Please note I had to grab the `setup_5.x` file instead of the `setup` file described in the guide.

The next problem was that I got a `Killed` message when doing `npm install`, partway through. This was because the machine I was running on had less than 512mb of ram and 256mb of swap. This sounds incredibly small but was a bare bones ubuntu server, well within the minimum specs and ran as a VM in a datacentre. I could install each individual package one at a time but the install all at once would run out of memory, and produce the `Killed` message. The only solution was to increase my ram and swap, or run it on a different machine and upload the files. Not ideal, but them's the breaks.

I now have it working properly.